# Как можно реализовать передачу аргументов в числовом представлении?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Рассмотрим данную воображаемую программу, которой можно передать 10 аргументов:

```
 program <список аргументов будет ниже> WORD1 WORD2
```

- `-arg--subarg1`
- `-arg--subarg2`
- `-arg--subarg3`
- `-arg--subarg4`
- `-arg--subarg5`
- `-arg--subarg6`
- `-arg--subarg7`
- `-arg--subarg8`
- `-arg--subarg9`
- `-arg--subarg0`

Предположим, что каждый конкретный аргумент что-то делает с **WORD1** и **WORD2**

Предположим, пользователю необходимо выполнить команду:

program -arg--subarg4 -arg--subarg7 -arg--subarg1 АНДРЕЙ ИВАНОВ

Которая преобразует **АНДРЕЙ ИВАНОВ** в следующий вид:

- `-arg--subarg4`

приведёт **АНДРЕЙ ИВАНОВ** к виду **Андрей Иванов**

- `-arg--subarg7`

добавит к **Андрей Иванов** `!`

- `-arg--subarg1`

поставит кавычки, и напечатает

> **"Андрей Иванов!"**

В общем,  всё это долго, и было  замечательно, если бы пользователь мог  ввести просто:

```
program -arg--471 АНДРЕЙ ИВАНОВ
```

И получить:

> **"Андрей Иванов!"**

Т.е. что имеется ввиду под  `-arg--471`? Под `-arg--471` имеется ввиду, что будут выполнены три аргумента; сначала 4-ый, затем 7-ой, и 1-ый.

---

Как это реализовать программно? У меня в голове только 1 мысль: if/else и т.п. вещи, которых будет просто бесчисленное количество.

---

Прошу при ответе на вопрос не ссылаться к [alias](/questions/tagged/alias)

---

**Update-1**: Хотя, наверное, использование [alias](/questions/tagged/alias) будет самым разумным решением.

Comment: Непонятно при чём тут Perl или bash. Определитесь. Далее, длинные опции начинаются с --. Что касается алгоритма, то это не так сложно. Надо лишь ввести разбор позиционных аргументов. И их уже раскладывать на составляющие. И да, 'alias' ничем тут не поможет.

Comment: И по поводу формата: ещё проще ввести опцию *--arg <LIST>*, которую очень просто разобрать, где *<LIST>*, например, *471*.

Comment: Perl:`Getops::Long`, BASH: `"$@"`